# jQuery: datepicker in chinese

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In a new app, the jquery datepicker is coming up in Chinese.

These are the scripts I am using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

There must be a list somewhere, with Chinese as the last item so getting chosen by default, or something like that, but I don't know.

So what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It looks like the version for internationalization/localization?

You already have before it:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So try removing the international version?

Comment: Many thanks @U-DON, I copied the scripts without thinking.  Nothing like thinking, is there...?

Comment: we pay the price for thinking ... ;-)